Escape HTML content in selectOptions
Need to Escape the html character from Selectlistoption without modifying backend logic
We have 4 level apex repeats , I have added a repeat as part of this question
 <apex:repeat value="{!acc.dControlList}" var="acc" id="controlRepeat">
<apex:selectList id="picklist_response" size="1" 
         value="{!dynamicObject[acc.record.Field_Name__c]}" 
               <apex:selectOptions value="{!acc.options}" />
   </apex:selectList> </apex:repeat>

are there any way to escap the HTMl as part of selectoption
  <apex:selectOptions value="{!acc.options}" />

I have checked the salesforce technical documentation, there mentioned we can use itemEscaped attribute to false, when I used that in code it shows unsupported attribute
  <apex:selectOptions value="{!acc.options}" itemEscaped="false"/>


itemEscaped applies to apex:selectOption, not apex:selectOptions. You could write this using apex:repeat:

<apex:selectList id="picklist_response" size="1" 
         value="{!dynamicObject[acc.record.Field_Name__c]}">
    <apex:repeat value="{!acc.options}" var="option">
      <apex:selectOption itemLabel="{!option.label}" 
        itemValue="{!option.value}" itemEscaped="false" />
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:selectList>

Note that if you disable this protection, you can introduce XSS (Cross Site Scripting) attacks, so use this with care.

I have many tags inside apex:repeat for shortening the question i have asked for apex:selectOptions, I can't use like that are there anyway we can fix it in apex:selectOption

@SFDCLearner No. apex:selectOptions works with the SelectOption class, which has three properties: label, value, and disabled. If you need to not escape the options, you must use apex:repeat.

Thanks, but HTML content is rendering in drop down, it's not escaping

@SFDCLearner A screenshot of the phenomenon would be helpful.
